# Pass "this" implicitly through inline event listener

Tags: javascript

```js
var fn = (function() {

  return {
    'init': function(className) {
      // Access <a> tag here and apply className
    }
  };

}());
```

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="fn.init('myClass')">Link</a>
```

In the above code snippet, would it be possible to implicitly pass `this` to `fn.init`?

I realize that I can change the declaration of `fn.init` to `function(className, el)` and use `onmouseover="fn.init('myClass', this)"` to access the element, but I am just curious if it would be possible without passing `this` in the inline event listener.

Comment: You probably should re-consider the use of inline event handlers in the first place. They have been ... out of fashion for *years* now. Maybe you're trying to solve a problem you wouldn't even have if you'd change your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `call` as well (I realize that you said you didn't want to pass `this` in the inline event listener, but this is probably the only way). The only other way is to use `addEventListener` and not use an inline event.

```js
var fn = (function() {

  return {
    'init': function(className) {
      // Notice that I can use "this" in this function
      // Which refers to the <a> element
      this.className = className;
    }
  };

}());
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="fn.init.call(this, 'myClass')">Link</a>
```

If you wanted to add an event to every `<a>` element, you would do this:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
  elems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    fn.init.call(this, 'myClass');
  }, false);
}
```

Or if you are using only modern browsers (no IE)

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
  elems[i].addEventListener("click", fn.init.bind(elems[i], 'myClass'), false);
}
```

Comment: That is, however, explicit, not implicit as the question asks.

Comment: @Quentin Just pointing out that it's possible to set the value of `this`, but not implicitly.

Comment: That is an interesting idea though. Say you wanted add an event listener to all `a` elements, would `this` stay respective to each element using this method?

Comment: @esswilly Yes, although if you are actually going to do it to all `<a>` elements, it's better to dynamically add it, because DRY. (Don't repeat yourself - you don't want to type `onmouseover=` every time)

Comment: I understand. So would something like `document.getElementsByTagName('a').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { fn.init.call(this, 'myClass'); } )` work?

Comment: @esswilly Unfortunately not, because `getElementsByTagName("a")` returns an list of nodes, and `addEventListener` doesn't work on lists (unfortunately, it would be cool if it `NodeList` had an `addEventListener` method). I'll update my answer with what you could use.

Answer (score 1):

No. You get a new value of `this` each time you call a function.

`fn.init('myClass')` is a different function call to `theElement.onmouseover(event)`.

You could use `addEventListener` to bind the event handler instead of using intrinsic event attributes.

Comment: Right, so even though `fn.init` is called in the scope of the `<a>` tag, the function has no way of knowing where in the DOM it was called?

Comment: Correct. There is no way to find out the value that the `this` variable (or any other variable) held in the function calling the current function.